# Call Class Methods to Initialize Static Class

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a singleton class that requires some sophisticated initialization.  I've boiled my problem down to this test case:

```
class Dumb
  attr_accessor :mything
  @my_thing = 1           # this works
  self.init_some_stuff    # this gives undefined method
  class << self
    def init_some_stuff
      @my_thing = 2
    end
    def spill_it
      puts "My Thing: #{@my_thing}"
    end
  end
end
```

I can initialize simple variables, but want to call class methods to do it, and I get "undefined method".  Since I intend it to be used as a singleton, a constructor would not get called.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why not initialise the class with a block?

Comment: @Mohamad:  Sorry, not following you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method is executed whenever it is met.

```
  self.init_some_stuff
```

is placed before the definition of it. That is the problem. Place it after the definition.